# Does Lebesgue integration have the property of countable subadditivity?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Does the following property valid for Lebesgue integration:

If $f$ is integrable on $E$ and $E = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_n$ then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{E_n} |f|\le \int_E |f|. $$

If it is true, can you give a reference where the proof is written, and if it is not true, can you give a counterexample?

Comment: If $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_n$ is  a partition of $E$, then we even have an equality. For the proof, try to rewrite the LHS as a limit and apply monotonous convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality that you wrote is clearly false if we take $E_n=E$ for all $n$. Actually, the reverse inequality is true. To see this, note that:

$|f|\cdot 1_E\leq\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} |f|\cdot 1_{E_n}$.

Now take an integral on both sides.

Comment: I agree.  The reverse of the OP is what we usually call "countably subadditive".